# Cannot stop setTimeout function using clearTimeout because value is null for some reason

Tags: javascript, typescript, settimeout, cleartimeout

In my react-native app, I'm trying to stop `setTimeout` using `clearTimeout`. I save an instance of the `setTimeout` in a global variable.

```
let timeoutId:any = null;

    const doOtp = ()=>{
        if(canSendOtp) {
            setCanSendOtp(false);

            timeoutId = setTimeout(() => { // it has here a numeric value
                showNotificationMessage("You can request OTP again")
                setCanSendOtp(true)
            }, SEND_OTP_TIME_CONSTRAINTS)

           // rest of doOtp logic
        }
        else {
            showNotificationMessage("Please wait " + (SEND_OTP_TIME_CONSTRAINTS / 1000) + " seconds before trying again")
        }
    }
```

Then when I want to stop the setTimeout using clearTimeout, I see that the value of `timeoutId` is `null`. I don't understand why it's happening.

```
const doLogin = () => {
issueToken(LOGIN_GRANT_TYPE, LOGIN_CLIENT_ID, LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET, phoneNumber, otp)
    .then(res => { 
        
        console.log('timeoutId !== null' + timeoutId !== null)
        if(timeoutId !== null) { // value here is null - why?
            clearTimeout(timeoutId)
        }

        store().dispatch(setTokenValidity(res))
    })
    .catch(err => {
        showNotificationMessage('Error, something went wrong check logs.')
        console.log("issueToken error: " + JSON.stringify(err))
    });
```

}

Comment: Just from those code snippets (and some favorable assumptions about the structure of the code) this should work -> Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PROBLEM

`setCanSendOtp(true)` updates your state which initializes your timeout to null again.

### SOLUTION

Put your timeout in Ref. Ref values are persistent across re-renders and state-updates.

```
const timeoutId:any = React.useRef(null);

const doOtp = ()=>{
        if(canSendOtp) {
            setCanSendOtp(false);

            timeoutId.current = setTimeout(() => { // it has here a numeric value
                showNotificationMessage("You can request OTP again")
                setCanSendOtp(true)
            }, SEND_OTP_TIME_CONSTRAINTS)

           // rest of doOtp logic
        }
        else {
            showNotificationMessage("Please wait " + (SEND_OTP_TIME_CONSTRAINTS / 1000) + " seconds before trying again")
        }
    }

const doLogin = () => {
issueToken(LOGIN_GRANT_TYPE, LOGIN_CLIENT_ID, LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET, phoneNumber, otp)
    .then(res => { 
        
        if(timeoutId.current !== null) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId.current)
        }

        store().dispatch(setTokenValidity(res))
    })
    .catch(err => {
        showNotificationMessage('Error, something went wrong check logs.')
        console.log("issueToken error: " + JSON.stringify(err))
    });
```